# Excel Data Validation- Numbers only and specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I am trying to use data validation in excel to allow a user to only input a number within a specific cell, otherwise, they can also type "unknown" within the same cell. Right now I'm using ISNUMBER function, however, I don't know how to include "unknown" too. I do not want this to be a dropdown list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom formula like this:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(A1),A1="unknown")
```

See screenshot for the data validation in action.
[image]

Comment: OP seems to have canceled his/her account so that there wouldn't be any response any more.